# QLabel Memory Leak on Thread

Tags: c++, qt

I found a memory leak issue with Qt and QLabel.

When starting a QThread from which I emit a signal to update the GUI and changing the text of the QLabel from the signal, it is noticeable (using Windows Task Manager) that the RAM increases rapidly.

The code to test this is very simple and is extracted from an application where, from the same thread and with the same signal, I change the text of different items, and the only one causing problems is the QLabel.

If instead of changing the text from the thread, I change it from a while loop in the main window, the problem does not occur.

**I emphasize that I change the text of multiple objects from the same thread without any memory leaks, and the application remains stable. Using QLabel after hours, the application reaches 2GB and becomes unmanageable.**

I have added a button to start the thread and the label in the mainwindow ui. The global g_MainFormUnit is the reference to the form. I use this tecnique all over in my code and this is not causing any problem elsewhere.
The code is compiled for Windows with Qt 6.4.2 MinGW 64Bit Debug.

Here is my code.

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include <QThread>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "spydriver_thread.h"
#include "shared.h"

    Ui::MainWindow      * g_MainFormUnit;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    g_MainFormUnit = ui;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_StartThreadButton_clicked()
{
    // Capture Thread to fill packets
    SpyDriver_ShowViewThread * workerThread = new SpyDriver_ShowViewThread ();
    workerThread->start();
    QObject::connect(workerThread, &SpyDriver_ShowViewThread::InsertPacket, workerThread, &SpyDriver_ShowViewThread::on_InsertPacket);

}
```

spydriver_thread.cpp

```
#include <QtCore>

// Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Qt Includes
#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QThread>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>

#include "spydriver_thread.h"
#include "shared.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

void SpyDriver_ShowViewThread::on_InsertPacket                (int in_Packet)
{
    char PacketCounterText [16];
    memset (PacketCounterText, 0, sizeof(PacketCounterText));
    sprintf (PacketCounterText, "[%05d]", in_Packet);

    g_MainFormUnit->SessionPacketNumberLabel->setText(QString(PacketCounterText));  // **This causes the memory leak**

    return;
}

// --- CONSTRUCTOR ---
SpyDriver_ShowViewThread::SpyDriver_ShowViewThread()
{
    return;
}

// --- DECONSTRUCTOR ---
SpyDriver_ShowViewThread::~SpyDriver_ShowViewThread()
{
    // free resources
    return;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_StartThreadButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

spydriver_thread.h

```
#ifndef __MULTISERIAL_SPYDRIVER_THREAD_H__
#define __MULTISERIAL_SPYDRIVER_THREAD_H__

#include <QtCore>

// Qt Includes
#include <QtGlobal>
#include <QThread>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>

#include <stdio.h>


class SpyDriver_ShowViewThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

    void run() override {
        int i = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            emit InsertPacket (i);
            i++;
        }
    }

public:
    SpyDriver_ShowViewThread();
    ~SpyDriver_ShowViewThread();

public slots:

    void on_InsertPacket                 (int in_Packet);

signals:

    void InsertPacket                (int in_Packet);

private:

};

#endif
```

shared.h

```
#ifndef SHARED_H
#define SHARED_H

#include    "mainwindow.h"

    extern Ui::MainWindow      * g_MainFormUnit;

#endif // SHARED_H
```

Comment: As coding suggestion, look up rule-of-0. Don't add any extra constructors or destructors, unless you have a concrete reason to do so (code does not work/compile without). (Note that the root base class of OOP class hierarchy needs to add virtual destructor, but QObject already does that)

Answer (score 0):

Your thread is emitting signals faster than the GUI thread can process them. They are queued, and queue size keeps growing.

Makes sense really, the GUI thread is doing a lot of other stuff too, such as updating the screen and processing OS events. Your worker thread OTOH is doing nothing but adding queued signals emits for GUI thread event loop.

Add a tiny sleep to worker thread, or add a semaphore between signal emit and receiving slot to limit the amount of queued signals.

---

General solution is to add a separate signal processing step, either in the emitting thread, or in another thread (or maybe in GUI thread). The intermediate step should keep track of the value UI should display, but only update the UI at some longer intervals. 100 ms interval is probably fine for any non-realtime non-game-like application.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. In my actual application, there are two threads: one adds packets to a list, and the other checks for new packets in the list. This essentially creates a semaphore-like mechanism. It's a kernel driver application for Windows, I need to be fast!
While I suspect the issue might lie with the QLabel, other objects updated earlier in the code don't exhibit any problems. This makes me unsure if GUI congestion is the root cause.

    It's true that Qt widgets can be susceptible to memory leaks. Are there any other suggestions you might have?

Comment: Quick update:
I've tried to set up a timer and call the QLabel settext and the problem remains.
If I call the  QLabel settext always with the same text  like "abcdef" there is no leak.
It seems like it does not deallocate memory while in the thread but... just for the QLabel

Comment: @Rick64 added a possible solution to signals getting queued up.

Comment: @Rick64 Add a debug counter (like a global `std::atomic<int64_t>`  which you inc when you emit signal and dec in the slot. See if it stays at 0 or grows.

Comment: "Add a debug counter (like a global std::atomic<int64_t> which you inc when you emit signal and dec in the slot. See if it stays at 0 or grows." can you be more specific? I am a bit lost.